# jsf primefaces fileupload and jquery conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I am new to jquery, primefaces and jsf. Also please forgive my language.

In my head tag i have `<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>`
and `<script src="assets/myQuery.js"></script>`

myQuery.js contains follwing code

```
(function($)
{
$(document).ready(function() {
     ....
});

function switchStylestyle(styleName)

})(jQuery);
```

this script is used for creating a cookie for css

Also in the same page i have a p:fileUpload controll.

In the beginning the cookie creating worked fine and the fileupload was not working. I mean when i select a file for uploading by clicking choose nothing happens.

So i put following in the head tag (nothing else changed).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Now the file upload works fine but the cookie is not created

following is the fileupload controll:

```
<p:fileUpload id="vaultFileUploader" style="margin-left: -5px;" name="jquery/jquery.js" fileUploadListener="#{myBean.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true" label="Choose File" update=":logoChange:companyLogo" sizeLimit="1000000" auto="true" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />
```

i think the reason for this issue is because of the conlict between the primefaces and jquery.

any helps are welcome...

Comment: Any errors in your Javascript console?

Comment: Sorry about that. i found the answer myself later the same day. i used <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js"
  target="head" /> instead of <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>